# Python sort array of arrays by template

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have array of arrays with arbitrary data, and need to sort them so that sub elements with specific key (unicorn) are at the end:

input: `[[1,2,'dog'], [2,2,'unicorn'], [2,3,'unicorn'], [3,3,'cat']]`
output: `[[1,2,'dog'], [3,3,'cat'], [2,2,'unicorn'], [2,3,'unicorn']]`

I am currently doing this by going once trough the array and moving the **unicrons** to a second array... 
and it gets ugly if I need to 'move' multiple keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python has a built-in function called [`sorted`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sorted). This takes an iterable (this list for example) and an optional key function. To sort in a way that all other elements have their relative positions unchanged, you could use something like this:

```
sorted([[1,2,'dog'], [2,2,'unicorn'], [2,3,'unicorn'], [3,3,'cat']],
       key=lambda v: 1 if v[2] == 'unicorn' else 0)
# [[1, 2, 'dog'], [3, 3, 'cat'], [2, 2, 'unicorn'], [2, 3, 'unicorn']]
```

Comment: I did not think of that. Although this seems too much magic to my liking to be instantly readable and understandable. However, everybody has their own style.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sort` function and provide it a key argument to sort based on the third element.
This way the array will be sorted "in place".

```
def sorter(el):
    if el[2] == 'unicorn':
        return 1
    return 0

arr = [[1,2,'dog'], [2,2,'unicorn'], [2,3,'unicorn'], [3,3,'cat']]

arr.sort(key=sorter)
```

You can also get same result by using `sorted` function
This way the `sorted` function will return a new array.

```
def sorter(el):
    if el[2] == 'unicorn':
        return 1
    return 0

arr = [[1,2,'dog'], [2,2,'unicorn'], [2,3,'unicorn'], [3,3,'cat']]  
sorted_arr = sorted(arr, key=sorter)
```

Comment: I ended up using a global function with lambda `sorted(arr, key=lambda: a: Helper.magic(a[1])`